# Identifying a random repeating pattern in a structured text string

Tags: php

I have a string that has the following structure:

`ABC_ABC_PQR_XYZ`

Where PQR has the structure:

`ABC+JKL`

and

`ABC` itself is a string that can contain alphanumeric characters and a few other characters like "_", "-", "+", "." and follows no set structure:

eg.`qWe_rtY-asdf` or `pkl123`

so, in effect, the string can look like this:

`qWe_rtY-asdf_qWe_rtY-asdf_qWe_rtY-asdf+JKL_XYZ`

My goal is to find out what string constitutes `ABC`.

I was initially just using

```
$arrString = explode("_",$string);
```

to return `$arrString[0]` before I was made aware that `ABC` (`$arrString[0]`) itself can contain underscores, thus rendering it incorrect.

My next attempt was exlpoding it on "_" anyway and then comparing each of the exploded string parts with the first string part until I get a semblance of a pattern:

```
function getPatternABC($string)
{
 $count  = 0;
 $pattern ="";

 $arrString = explode("_", $string);

 foreach($arrString as $expString)
 {
    if(strcmp($expString,$arrString[0])!==0 || $count==0)
{
   $pattern = $pattern ."_". $arrString[$count];
   $count++;
    }
    else break;
 }

 return substr($pattern,1);
}
```

This works great - but I wanted to know if there was a more elegant way of doing this using regular expressions?

Comment: It looks like this method will fail if ABC has a value of x_y_x

Comment: it does indeed fail for `x_y_x` :(

Comment: Wow, so many answers and so fast! Please teach me how to be a regex guru!!! :)

Comment: One site I used for reference in the past was http://www.regular-expressions.info/. Then I bought their program -- saves time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex solution:

```
'^([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)_\1_\1\+'
```

What this does is match (starting from the beginning of the string) the longest possible sequence consisting of the characters inside the square brackets (edit that per your spec). The sequence must appear exactly twice, each time followed by an underscore, and then must appear once more followed by a plus sign (this is actually the first half of `PQR` with the delimiter before `JKL`). The rest of the input is ignored.

You will find `ABC` captured as capture group 1.

So:

```
$input = 'qWe_rtY-asdf_qWe_rtY-asdf_qWe_rtY-asdf+JKL_XYZ';
$result = preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)_\1_\1\+/', $input, $matches);
if ($result) {
    echo $matches[2];
}
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/GNLZK).

Comment: my version is probably not as tidy: `/^(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)_\2_\2)/`

Comment: This fails if the sequence is repeated within the "key" itself: 1234_1234_1234+ would match. Depends on how bad he wants to compensate for pathological cases.

Comment: Thanks Jon! That seems to work for the string in my question but if I give it a more complex string like when `ABC` = 'qWe_rtY-asdf+87dhd-8dshs_a7sdg_bndhd7' then it doesn't work ... How would the regex look in this case?

Comment: If I combine your and Anomie's solution, like so: `preg_match('/^(([a-zA-Z0-9_+.-]+)_){2}\2\+/', $string, $matches);` then it works ... thank you Jon and Anomie!

Comment: @mythical_man_moth: Works for me. **Remember that you have to put the "legal" characters inside the square brackets.** I used `^(([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)_){2}\2\+` (added plus sign, digits 0-9)

Comment: @SilverbackNet - I see what you mean. This string fails: `1234_1234_1234_1234_1234_1234_1234_1234_1234+1234_1234_1234_XYZ`

Comment: @SilverbackNet, @mythical: Yup, you 're right. Thought about it the wrong way. Fixed now.

Comment: that works perfectly ... although it should be $matches[1] :) thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just make a regular expression that matches your pattern. In this case, something like this:

```
preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9_+.-]+)_\1_\1\+JKL_XYZ$/', $string, $match);
```

Your ABC is in $match[1].

Answer (score 0):

If the presence of underscores in these strings has a low frequency, it may be worth checking to see if a simple explode() will do it before bothering with regex.

```
<?php
$str = 'ABC_ABC_PQR_XYZ';
if(substr_count($str, '_') == 3)
   $abc = reset(explode('_', $str));
else
   $abc = regexy_function($str);
?>
```

Comment: that makes sense ... the presence of underscores indeed has aTlow frequency but that could change over time as I get more data. Thanks!